# Trait Bound Not Satisfied sqlx query_as

Tags: rust, sqlx

Trying to get past an error in rust and sqlx (0.7x) using query_as and fetch_all functions and a defined struct. Goal is to query from sqlite and deserialize to a vec of struct.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use sqlx::sqlite::SqlitePoolOptions;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Todo {
    id: String,
    completed: bool,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // set up connection pool
    let pool = SqlitePoolOptions::new()
        // .max_connections(5)
        // .acquire_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3))
        .connect("sqlite:mydatabase.db")
        .await
        .expect("can't connect to database");

    let todos: Vec<Todo> = sqlx::query_as::<_, Todo>("SELECT * FROM todos")
        .fetch_all(&pool)
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
the trait bound `for<'r> Todo: FromRow<'r, _>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `FromRow<'r, R>`:
  ()
  (T1,)
  (T1, T2)
  (T1, T2, T3)
  (T1, T2, T3, T4)
  (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
  (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
  (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)
and 9 others

the method `fetch_all` exists for struct `QueryAs<'_, _, Todo, _>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`Todo: FromRow<'r, _>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `FromRow` resolved this issue:

```rust
use sqlx::{FromRow};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, FromRow)]
struct Todo {
    id: String,
    completed: bool,
}
```